# How to pass arguments from a table to a modal in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I need some help with a function or two.

I'm trying to pass an object to a modal ( or pop-up how I defined it ) and I've done that, but when I try to hit the "Save changes" button from the modal I hit a brick wall, the object is empty. I need to update the JSON object with a new name. I know I have to create a controller and a directive to this angular, but I don't know how to start. I already have the update functions stored in other controllers. I'm doing all this on a single page, the 'index.html'. Any suggestions on how I can do this ?

Thanks in advance.

PS: If there is anything needed, please tell me to post. Thanks again.

```
 angular.module('ConsultantCompany').controller('CompanyController', ['CompanyService', '$scope', '$log', function(CompanyService, $scope, $log) {
        var ctrl = this;

        ctrl.updateCompany = function(form) {
            CompanyService.update(form);
            $log.info("Company updated");
        }

        ctrl.updating = function(company) {
            $log.info("Company: ", company);

            $('#popup-1').fadeIn(250);
        }
}]);

<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Company ID</th>
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>Update</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="company in compCtrl.companies">
                <td>{{company.id}}</td>
                <td>{{company.name}}</td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-ng-click="compCtrl.updating(company)">Update</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-ng-click="compCtrl.deleteCompany(company)">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<form name="form" id="name" data-ng-submit="compCtrl.updateCompany(form)" novalidate>
        <h1>Updating company: </h1>
        <label>Company name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the new name of the company you want to update" required>
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-ng-click="compCtrl.updateCompany(form)">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="close_popup(1);">Close</button>   
    </form>
```

Comment: Did you notice that in updateCompany method you have an argument called form and in the body you use a company variable?

Comment: @andale, Sorry, my bad I must've messed up the variables when I pasted the code here.

Comment: Your code works as expected http://plnkr.co/edit/vZqb4PH7SmHFk2RMqiFb?p=preview I get `Company:  Object {id: 1, name: "John", $$hashKey: "object:3"}`

Comment: @andale It works like this, but when I hit the save changes button it should pass the object, but it doesn't and my java back end gets a null pointer exception ... :(